# scrapy accessing inner URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a url in start_urls array as below:

```
start_urls = [
        'https://www.ebay.com/sch/tp_peacesports/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from='
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        shop_title = self.getShopTitle(response)
        sell_count = self.getSellCount(response)
        self.shopParser(response, shop_title, sell_count)


    def shopParser(self, response, shop_title, sell_count):
        items = EbayItem()
        items['shop_title'] = shop_title
        items['sell_count'] = sell_count
        if sell_count > 0:
            item_links = response.xpath('//ul[@id="ListViewInner"]/li/h3/a/@href').extract()
            for link in item_links:
                items['item_price'] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract_first()

        yield items
```

now in shopParser() inside for loop I have different link and I need to have different **response** than the original response from start_urls, how I can achive that ?

Comment: have a  look at [this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects), you can do `scrapy.Request(link)`.

Comment: I have tried it but the newResponse.body is empty
like:
`new_response = scrapy.request('url')
print new_reponse.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call requests to new pages, otherwise you will not get any new html. Try something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    shop_title = response.meta.get('shop_title', self.getShopTitle(response))
    sell_count = response.meta.get('sell_count', self.getSellCount(response))

    # here you logic with item parsing
    if sell_count > 0:
        item_links = response.xpath('//ul[@id="ListViewInner"]/li/h3/a/@href').extract()
        # yield requests to next pages
        for link in item_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), meta={'shop_title': shop_title, 'sell_count': sell_count})
```

These new requests will also be parsed by `parse` function. Or you can set another callback, if needed.